# Upload Instant App problem: The configuration APKs in your Instant App APKs should have targeting information

Tags: android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

I am developing an instant app and have an issue with uploading to play console internal track.

I successfully built bundle with **./gradlew bundleRelease** command, than generated apks with **bundletool** with **mode instant** enabled and launched instant app locally with **ia tool**.

But when I try upload apks.zip to play console I've got an error *"The configuration APKs in your Instant App APKs should have targeting information."*

What does mean this message? Can it be connected with bundletool? Or could you advise how correctly upload instant app apks.zip to play console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Configuration APKs. They didn't have targetSdk information. I fixed it by adding this to build.gradle

```
 bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        density {
            enableSplit = false
        }
        abi {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in manifest tag in your manifext file

```
android:targetSandboxVersion="2"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I have android:targetSandboxVersion="2" in all manifest files of configurations apk's

Comment: Please share more details. Can help