# Is it obligatory to use Google Play Signing for Instant Apps now?

Tags: google-play-console, android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

I've already asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770444/upload-instant-app-problem-the-configuration-apks-in-your-instant-app-apks-shou) question, but now I think may be the reason in app signing. But there is opportunity to upload instant app as .zip of apks. So is anybody know if it is obligatory to use Google Play Signing for Instant Apps now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out it's not obligatory to use Google Play Signing for Instant Apps. We can use our local key to sign IA